# Merge Table Cell using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a problem in merging table cell in using AngularJS, I want to merge the data that has the same data with the next row using rowspan supposedly. But my problem is on checking the data.

Current output:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Here is my current code:

```
<div>
   <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th class="col-xs-1">Report Trail ID</th>
                      <th class="col-xs-5">Field Name</th>
                      <th class="col-xs-6">Change</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr ng-show="dataEntryCtrl.auditTrail == 0">
                      <td colspan="6" align="center">No records found.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr dir-paginate="audit in dataEntryCtrl.auditTrail | itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="paginate2">
                      <td class="text-center">
                          {{dataEntryCtrl.reportTrailId}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          {{audit.FieldName}}
                      </td>
                      <td ng-bind-html="dataEntryCtrl.trusthtml(audit.Changes)">
                      </td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
          </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea about this?

Updated results using @Himanshu Aggarwal code:
[image]

Comment: you have to iterate over change texts and determine the rowspan number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to do some pre-processing of your data to work out whether there are multiple rows, I have an example below:

```js
(function() {

  angular
    .module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

  angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("AppController", AppController);

  AppController.$inject = ["$scope"];

  function AppController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    setup();

    function setup(){
      vm.myArray = loadData();
      calculateRows();
    }


    function loadData() {
     return [{
        "reportTrailId": 658,
        "fieldName": "Manufacturer 1",
        "change": "<span>change 1</span>"
      }, {
        "reportTrailId": 659,
        "fieldName": "Manufacturer 2",
        "change": "<span>change 2</span>"
      }, {
        "reportTrailId": 660,
        "fieldName": "Manufacturer 2",
        "change": "<span>change 3</span>"
      }, {
        "reportTrailId": 661,
        "fieldName": "Manufacturer 3",
        "change": "<span>change 4</span>"
      }, ];
    }

    function calculateRows() {
      if (vm.myArray.length > 0) {
        vm.myArray[0].matchPreviousRow=false;
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.myArray.length; i++) {
          var field = vm.myArray[i].fieldName;
          var rows = 1;
          for (var j = i + 1; j < vm.myArray.length; j++) {
            if (vm.myArray[j].fieldName === field && ! vm.myArray[j].matchPreviousRow) {
              rows++;
              vm.myArray[j].matchPreviousRow=true;
            } else {
              vm.myArray[j].matchPreviousRow=false;
              break;
            }
          }
          vm.myArray[i].rows = rows;
        }
      }
    }


  }


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController as vm">
  
<div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th class="col-xs-1">Report Trail ID</th>
                      <th class="col-xs-5">Field Name</th>
                      <th class="col-xs-6">Change</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr ng-show="dataEntryCtrl.auditTrail == 0">
                      <td colspan="6" align="center">No records found.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.myArray">
                      <td class="text-center">
                          {{item.reportTrailId}}
                      </td>
                      <td rowSpan="{{item.rows}}" ng-if="! item.matchPreviousRow">
                          {{item.fieldName}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{item.change}}
                      </td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
          </table>
     </div>
</div>
  


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's working when the rowspan is equal to 2, but there's something wrong when rowspan became 3.

Comment: I made some changes to calculate function and it's WORK now. Thanks for the idea @John. Cheers!

Comment: @kwingkwing.ko what change you did to support for more than 3 rowspan?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 components you have to manage in order to obtain the desired result:
1) The html: you could use the "rowspan" attribute to merge the cells
2) The data source: you need to bind the data to the html, using a structure like that:

```
[{ 
   "change": "sdf", 
   "rows": [
        {
            "reportTrailId": 658
            "fieldName": "Manufacturer name"
        },
        ...
},...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, make use of `$index` -

```
<tr dir-paginate="audit in dataEntryCtrl.auditTrail | itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="paginate2">
    <td class="text-center">
        {{dataEntryCtrl.reportTrailId}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{audit.FieldName}}
    </td>
    <td ng-if="(audit.Changes === dataEntryCtrl.auditTrail[$index + 1].Changes)" rowspan="(audit.Changes === dataEntryCtrl.auditTrail[$index + 1].Changes) ? 2 : ''" ng-bind-html="dataEntryCtrl.trusthtml(audit.Changes)">
    </td>
    <td ng-if="(audit.Changes !== dataEntryCtrl.auditTrail[$index - 1].Changes)" ng-bind-html="dataEntryCtrl.trusthtml(audit.Changes)">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hey it's working but the problem is it's limited for only 2 rowspan, it should be dynamic because what if there are 3 rows that has the same data value. Please see the updated image above.